# Formatting Counter Data in a Table in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, formatting, performancecounter

I'm attempting to create a table for monitoring purposes using the following script:

```
$w3wppriv = get-counter '\process(w3w*)\working set - private'
$w3wpid = get-counter '\process(w3w*)\id process'

0..($w3wpid.Length -1) | 
select-object (
   @{n="Proces ID"; e={$w3wpid.CounterSamples.Cookedvalue[$_]}},
   @{n="Memory Usage(KB)";  e={$w3wppriv.CounterSamples.CookedValue[$_]}}
              ) | 
   format-table -auto;
```

I'm attempting to get the following output:

```
Process ID Memory Usage(KB)
---------- ----------------
44353      234324343
35343      230909324
2341       932423234
```

However, the output is not displaying any data. I imagine it has something to do with the arrays but I am unclear how to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out...took me an hour :) Can't post for 8 but here's the answer:

Comment: $w3wppriv = ((get-counter -counter '\process(w3w*)\working set - private').CounterSamples) | select-object -expandproperty cookedvalue
    $w3wpid = ((get-counter '\process(w3w*)\id process').CounterSamples) | select-object -expandproperty cookedvalue

    0..($w3wpid.Length -1) | 
       select-object (
           @{n="Proces ID"; e={$w3wpid[$_]}},
        @{n="Memory Usage(KB)";  e={$w3wppriv[$_]}}
              ) | 
       format-table -auto;

Comment: I must be missing something.  Couldn't you just do this:  Get-Process | Format-Table -property Id, WS -autosize

Comment: I'm looking for workingset -private...very different from ws.

Comment: Well, you can output any property of 'Get-Process' that you see when you run 'get-process | get-member', but that wasn't really the point.  I was just suggesting that you could maybe use 'get-process' in a more direction fashion than 'get-counter'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example of knowing nothing but how to search :)

```
$w3wppriv = ((get-counter -counter '\process(w3w*)\working set - private').CounterSamples) | select-object -expandproperty cookedvalue
$w3wpid = ((get-counter '\process(w3w*)\id process').CounterSamples) | select-object -expandproperty cookedvalue

0..($w3wpid.Length -1) | 
   select-object (
       @{n="Proces ID"; e={$w3wpid[$_]}},
       @{n="Memory Usage(KB)";  e={$w3wppriv[$_]}}
          ) | 
   format-table -auto;
```